# How do I deal with episodic insomnia during puberty

Tags: sleep

Hello there I know this is probably off-topic for this community but I really need help, and was the closest QnA site for health that I found.  Plus, I am already a StackExchange user. I also tried searching it on Google, and couldn't find it.

---

Here is the issue I am a 15 year old male, who suffers sometimes with episodic insomnia like a day or two in one or two months.

For example, last Sunday-Monday night I had trouble sleeping.  I figured that since I couldn't fall asleep I might of well do something. So I decided to do a fun project at 9-11PM.  The Project was making a laptop into a keyboard desktop computer, since the monitor was badly damage with cracks and light spots.  When I started the project I was tired, and when I got finish with it dead tired.  so I went to bed at like 1:30 AM for the second time, and fall asleep at properly 3-4 AM.  So when I went to school, I brought about 1  liter of coffee with me.  (I don't drink coffee that much like once in a month or something on those lines, and that is the same with tea, soda, and chocolate.  So I don't have that much caffeine tolerance. BTW the coffee tasted mildly bitter.) I was tired thoughout the day, and when I got home, dead tired.  Well I went to bed at 6PM, and 6 hour later about 12:30AM right now.  Still tired and can't fall asleep but I am dead tired.  And I am a human who needs at least ~9.5-11 hours of sleep to not feel tired the next day.

So does anyone know tricks how to go to sleep?  I couldn't find any.  You may say music but it only tired me to a point before keeping me up.  Or take sleeping drugs, but the last time when this I took Melatonin.  And the only thing that did for me was make me more tired, without helping me go to sleep.  Right now I feel dead tired with a somewhat awake feeling.  It is an odd, annoying feeling and hard to explain.

Comment: If you know any better website to post this question on, please let me know.  And don't say like Yahoo Answers because there are people on their who will say anything.

Comment: There are people on here that will say anything as well. Internet advice is worth what you pay for it. Go see a doctor.

Comment: Second the recommendation for a doctor, but while you are waiting for an appointment - what kind of exercise are you getting?  Many studies have shown that regular, moderate intensity exercise helps with insomnia.  I would start with that, and a self-imposed prohibition on flickering screens in the hour before you want to fall asleep.  See a doctor, but if he prescribes pills without examining your physical activity levels, go get a second opinion.

Comment: @Adam +1 for suggesting the second opinion of pills are prescribed with no real examination.  I've had certain foods suggested to me for pre-bedtime including porridge.   Not sure how true it is, but might be worth a try.